# If s is a (global) section of a quasi coherent sheaf F on a scheme X, is there a reasonable scheme structure to gives its vanishing locus?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

(Other than the reduced induced subscheme structure on any closed set.. though now I'm not sure if the vanishing of a section of an arbitrary quasi coherent sheaf is actually closed in general.)

I know what to do if F is locally free, I am just wondering if someone means a particular scheme when they discuss the vanishing of such a section, or just a set.

(By vanishing of the section s I mean the set of primes where s is zero in the fiber / pullback to spec of the residue field at that point. At least I think it is a closed set... )

For context I am looking at Ravi Foundations... 16.3.7 (6) right now.

Comment: Could you give an example? In my experience it depends on the situation. I don't know of a way to do it for all sheaves.

Comment: @Hoot I don't have a particular example in mind. I was just wondering how to intepret part 6 of Ravi 16.3.7.

Comment: @Hoot I think a skyscraper sheaf of the stalk at a point gives an example of a quasi coherent sheaf where the vanishing of some element (the element 1) is actually an open set, not closed.

Comment: He probably just means as sets.

Comment: If you had a global section of the *dual* of a quasicoherent sheaf then that would give a morphism from X to $\mathbf{V}(\mathcal{E})$ (relative spec of sym on your bundle). You also have the zero section, always, and then you can form the fiber product of schemes to put a scheme structure on the zero locus.

Comment: Typically, first you may restrict your attention to the support of $F$, which has a natural scheme structure. Giving a section is a map $\mathcal{O}_X\to F$ and thus dualizing get a map $F^*\to\mathcal{O}_X$. The image is an ideal sheaf defining a closed subscheme, where the section vanishes.